# how to give better abstraction for sql queries used for php rest api?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have made basic Rest ApI using `php pdo`. But each queries are scattered all over the classess. How can I provide an abstraction to use it in better way; or what are the best practices to use sql queries in php file?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not satisfied with the abstraction provided by PDO, why not try something new, an ORM? doctrine ORM is what i prefer, it makes life so easy, with the mammoth of features it has to offer, plus it takes the MVC approach making it much easier for me to maintain my code, doctrine can generate the classes automatically for you and map it to the table. plus some of the features like automatic detection of relationship between tables, timestampable behaviors, migrations, soft deletes, makes it more spicier. it is not that hard to get started, i found there documentation to be the most helpful resource to understand the usage as they explain everything with the examples.

you can get more information in there website :  http://www.doctrine-project.org/

P.S: there are other ORM too like Propel, Red Bean, etc.

if you are looking for a light weight ORM, you can have a look at NotOrm, and here is the link to the tutorial

http://phpmaster.com/database-interaction-made-easy-with-notorm/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=facebook&utm_campaign=database-interaction-made-easy-with-notorm

that might help you to get started.

Comment: It may help me if i change my current implementation,i didn't check it though. But i want to work with my  current code and want to improve it.

Comment: i am afraid PHP offers no magic for what you want to do. the best approach one can think of for this situation is of MVC, as it offers more maintainable code, what i would suggest is to give active data approach to your models classes, that is create each class with corresponding table names, and place the class/methods to the belonging tables. google for more info about active record approach.